# PDA vb install release

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a PDA device, I’m developing a WinForms application. I’m testing my application on simulator. Once finished my tests, I need to put a release version of the application on the  PDA Device. I prefer to avoid the USB connection.  Is that possible?
Thankful for your help.

Comment: more info is necessary!  I am assuming since you said WinForms that the application is not meant for a win8 or win10 device but something older?  when you compile a CAB file should be generated which needs to be copied to the device.  once on the device simply click that CAB file to initiate an install.  if the app is meant for win8 or win10 then your terminology is incorrect.  basically a usb connection is necessary

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, as long as the device supports the version of the framework you are working with. You should, be able to drop the applications executable straight into a directory in the PDA, and run the program from there.

Comment: umm no that is not possible.  it will need to be installed first.  all windows 'PDA's' need to have the apps installed.  latest win8 and win10 devices have their apps installed from the store.  if they are development devices then the device needs to be connected via USB to install that app.  to avoid using a usb connection the app needs to be submitted to the store and installed via the store app on the device.  OR if the device is older then the cab file that is generated needs to be copied to device (using usb) and opened which will initiate and install